# Forbidden: field can not be less than previous value

Tags: jenkins-x

I got a problem on Azure that the Nexus didn't had enough disk space. Nexus failed to start due to this problem so I extended the default PVC jenkins-x-nexus from 8GB to 20GB. This extension was successful and everything is just running file.

But if I now want to upgrade my jx platform (jx upgrade platform) I'm getting the following error:

The PersistentVolumeClaim "jenkins-x-nexus" is invalid: spec.resources.requests.storage: Forbidden: field can not be less than previous value'

How can this be resolved?

The PersistentVolumeClaim "jenkins-x-nexus" is invalid: spec.resources.requests.storage: Forbidden: field can not be less than previous value'

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing a jx upgrade platform, Helm values for Nexus chart are populated from default Nexus chart Helm values - https://github.com/jenkins-x-charts/nexus/blob/master/nexus/values.yaml

If you want to override them, and I guess you do, since you need to specify the correct size of the PVC (>8Gb), you need to specify your custom values in `myvalues.yaml` file and place it in the same directory, where you're executing a `jx upgrade platform` and then run a `jx upgrade platform`
Please use https://jenkins-x.io/docs/managing-jx/old/config/#nexus as reference